# Steps to extract values from "USER INTERFACE" custom window textbox into my code, WHILE CREATING A SET UP PROJECT?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools

HI, I have created a setUp project for my windows application. 
My Solution has 2 Projects(1st is the Windows application and 2nd project is the setUp project that I added)I want to add custom welcome screens during installtion, so I did the following actions.

**1) Created a setUp project and added it to solution having a windows application.

2) Added the primary output of the only windows application (within the solution) to the setUp project.

3) Right click on SetUp project -> VIEW -> USER INTERFACES;  then added a textboxA.

4) Right click on SetUp project -> CUSTOM ACTIONS; This has 4 options Install, UnInstall,Commit,RollBack.

5) Added a new class to the Windows Application project, inherited "Installer" class to this new class. Overridded "Install" method of this class.

6)Right Click on INSTALL option -> ADD CUSTOM ACTION; and the primary output of the windows application was already added, so I didnt add anything.**
HERE THE WINDOWS APPLICATION PROJECT HAS BOTH APPLICATION CODE AND ALSO THE OVERRIDDED Install METHOD.
bUT WHEN i TRY TO INSTALL THIS ITS SHOWING SOME ERROR CODE **2869**.

Kindly help me with the procedure to extract values from custom textBox into my overridden Install method.

Comment: DID YOU KNOW THAT UPPER CASE LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING?

Comment: Hi pardon me for that. I just wanted to highlight. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking I have no idea if it is possible to add anything custom to VS setup project.

I had a similar issue and soon lost my patience and migrated to WiX. It integrates with VS very well (you can add WiX XML schema to have your code coloured and Intelisense enabled). With Wix you can do far more custom things than in VS Setup.

Moreover WiX has a great community, loads of examples and last but not least, you can adjust user interface as the VS Setup projects look REALLY ugly.

Comment: No actually we can add custom screens, prompt screens prompting user to enter some input. To achieve this one has to override "Install" method of "Installer" class of System.Configuration.Install namespace. I actually overrided this "Install" method but I am NOT ABLE TO EXTRACT CUSTOM INPUT VALUES WHICH THE USER WOULD ENTER TO THE CUSTOM SCREENS THAT I HAD ADDED(in the User Interface option of Set Up project).